# Batch Expired exception when the batch size is 0

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

In what situation can you get the error `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Batch Expired` when trying to send a message with the Kafka Producer when `batch.size=0`? I don't understand how if I'm not batching my messages I can get a batch expire error. Or is it just that the "batch" only has one message in it, and that message expired before it could be sent?

Comment: looks like your kafka server is down.